# New column based on information from subsequent encounters when each row represents an individual

Tags: r, tidyverse

I am using "dplyr" package in R to summarize and re-organize a dataset. The dataset is composed of individual records and for each individual there may be a unique or multiple encounters. I would like to create a new column that considers information from subsequent encounters if the data collected during the first one was incomplete. Here is some example data:

```
  ID<-rep(1:4,2)
  Time<-as.character(c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B"))
  Color<- as.character(c("u","u","red","red","green","u","u","red"))
  Data<- data.frame(ID,Time,Color)
  Data
```

For the above data example I would like to create a new column for color. For those individuals (ID) that were encountered in Time A that have "u" Color (this represents unknown), change Color to the identified kind in a subsequent time (Time B). Otherwise, if it has a color kind during Time A, keep as is. Here is what I've tried:

```
 library(dplyr)
 Data2<-mutate(Data, Color.new=if_else(Color=="u" & Time=="A", 
 Color=="green"|Color=="red"  & Time=="B", NA))
 Data2
```

I'm hoping that reads: When Color is "u" and Time is "A" then Color is its respective value (either green or red) when Time is "B", otherwise it stays as is.

My trial doesn't work and it results in a column with NAs and FALSE when for example individual 1 could have changed from unknown to green.

Thanks for your help or comments.

Comment: Quick question - can each individual have multiple time "B"s or just one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your ifelse statement doesn't work is because it's designed to work on vectors: a vector of things to compare, and two vectors of possible responses.  All of these have to be the same length.  That's not really going to work in your case.  There are two ways I can see approaching the solution:

1) If each individual has at most 1 time "B" observation, the easiest solution is to use spread and gather from the `tidyr` package.  (These have the same function as `reshape`, and there are a lot of other functions that do this same thing - this is just the one I like.

```
result <- Data %>%
  spread(Time, Color) %>%
  mutate(
    A = as.character(A),
    B = as.character(B),
    Color1 = case_when(
    A == 'u' ~ B,
    B == 'u' ~ A,
    TRUE ~ A
  )) %>% # only run this if you want to go back to the long format
  gather(Time, Color, A:B)
#   ID Color1 Time Color
# 1  1  green    A     u
# 2  2      u    A     u
# 3  3    red    A   red
# 4  4    red    A   red
# 5  1  green    B green
# 6  2      u    B     u
# 7  3    red    B     u
# 8  4    red    B   red
```

If you can have multiple `B`s, then an approach using summaries might work better:

```
Data %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarize(
    Color1 = if(sum(Color != "u") > 0) paste(unique(Color[Color != "u"]), collapse = "_") else "u"
  ) %>%
  left_join(Data, .)

#   ID Time Color Color1
# 1  1    A     u  green
# 2  2    A     u      u
# 3  3    A   red    red
# 4  4    A   red    red
# 5  1    B green  green
# 6  2    B     u      u
# 7  3    B     u    red
# 8  4    B   red    red
```

Comment: In this solution, the responses are propagating in both directions.  If you want it to be only one direction, that can be changed very easily - just let me know.

Comment: (I just fixed a typo in the first solution - both should work as expected now)

Comment: Option 2 is what I was looking for as each individual may be encountered again or not. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tidyr::fill`

```
library(tidyverse)
Data[Data =="u"] <- NA

Data %>% group_by(ID) %>% fill(Color,.direction = "up") %>% ungroup
# # A tibble: 8 x 3
#      ID   Time  Color
#   <int> <fctr> <fctr>
# 1     1      A  green
# 2     1      B  green
# 3     2      A   <NA>
# 4     2      B   <NA>
# 5     3      A    red
# 6     3      B   <NA>
# 7     4      A    red
# 8     4      B    red
```

Here we don't have the subsequent info for a few cases so some `NAs` remain.

Comment: This result seems correct to me; not sure why it's downvoted.

Comment: maybe the row order, or the remaining NAs didn't look good to someone :)